# Build promotion using jenkins upon servicenow change request approval

Tags: jenkins, servicenow

Build promotion using jenkins upon servicenow change request approval

I need to promote my build to production environment only when my change request# "CHXXXX" has approved? How to achieve this using Jenkins/Servicenow integration?
Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's pretty generic.. I assume Jenkins has a build API?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is handled by using a "run script" activity in ServiceNow's change workflow.

In your case, you'd have to do the following:

1. Set up your Jenkins Web service in ServiceNow ([REST Web Service Tutorial](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/training/article/app_store_learnv2_rest_madrid_outbound_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_madrid_outbound_integrations_in_servicenow_objectives?v=madrid))
2. Capture somewhere the Jenkins Pipeline to run (recommendation: on the Configuration Item)
3. Add the "run script" activity to your Change Management approval workflow in ServiceNow to call the Jenkins API after approval has been granted. You could even introduce a timer to wait until the "planned start" time.
4. Make sure you capture the Jenkins result / output in your Change ticket for reference.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any Jenkins plugin which is used to verify the status of the approval in servicenow